# How to detect keyboard events in SwiftUI on macOS?

Tags: swiftui, keydown

How can I detect keyboard events in a SwiftUI view on macOS?

I want to be able to use key strokes to control items on a particular screen but it's not clear how I detect keyboard events, which is usually done by overriding the `keyDown(_ event: NSEvent)` in `NSView`.

Answer (score 44):

New in SwiftUI bundled with Xcode 12 is the `commands` modifier, which allows us to declare key input with [`keyboardShortcut` view modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/keyboardshortcut). You then need some way of forwarding the key inputs to your child views. Below is a solution using a `Subject`, but since it is not a reference type it cannot be passed using `environmentObject` - which is really what we wanna do, so I've made a small wrapper, conforming to `ObservableObject` and for conveninece `Subject` itself (forwarding via the `subject`).

Using some additional convenience sugar methods, I can just write like this:

```swift
.commands {
    CommandMenu("Input") {
        keyInput(.leftArrow)
        keyInput(.rightArrow)
        keyInput(.upArrow)
        keyInput(.downArrow)
        keyInput(.space)
    }
}
```

And forward key inputs to all subviews like this:

```swift
.environmentObject(keyInputSubject)
```

And then a child view, here `GameView` can listen to the events with `onReceive`, like so:

```swift
struct GameView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var keyInputSubjectWrapper: KeyInputSubjectWrapper
    @StateObject var game: Game
        
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            board
            info
        }.onReceive(keyInputSubjectWrapper) {
            game.keyInput($0)
        }
    }
}
```

The `keyInput` method used to declare the keys inside `CommandMenu` builder is just this:

```swift
private extension ItsRainingPolygonsApp {
    func keyInput(_ key: KeyEquivalent, modifiers: EventModifiers = .none) -> some View {
        keyboardShortcut(key, sender: keyInputSubject, modifiers: modifiers)
    }
}
```

[image: tetris_game]

## Full Code

```swift
extension KeyEquivalent: Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.character == rhs.character
    }
}

public typealias KeyInputSubject = PassthroughSubject<KeyEquivalent, Never>

public final class KeyInputSubjectWrapper: ObservableObject, Subject {
    public func send(_ value: Output) {
        objectWillChange.send(value)
    }
    
    public func send(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Failure>) {
        objectWillChange.send(completion: completion)
    }
    
    public func send(subscription: Subscription) {
        objectWillChange.send(subscription: subscription)
    }
    

    public typealias ObjectWillChangePublisher = KeyInputSubject
    public let objectWillChange: ObjectWillChangePublisher
    public init(subject: ObjectWillChangePublisher = .init()) {
        objectWillChange = subject
    }
}

// MARK: Publisher Conformance
public extension KeyInputSubjectWrapper {
    typealias Output = KeyInputSubject.Output
    typealias Failure = KeyInputSubject.Failure
    
    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, S.Failure == Failure, S.Input == Output {
        objectWillChange.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
    }
}
    

@main
struct ItsRainingPolygonsApp: App {
    
    private let keyInputSubject = KeyInputSubjectWrapper()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
            #if os(macOS)
            ContentView()
                .frame(idealWidth: .infinity, idealHeight: .infinity)
                .onReceive(keyInputSubject) {
                    print("Key pressed: \($0)")
                }
                .environmentObject(keyInputSubject)
            #else
            ContentView()
            #endif
        }
        .commands {
            CommandMenu("Input") {
                keyInput(.leftArrow)
                keyInput(.rightArrow)
                keyInput(.upArrow)
                keyInput(.downArrow)
                keyInput(.space)
            }
        }
    }
}

private extension ItsRainingPolygonsApp {
    func keyInput(_ key: KeyEquivalent, modifiers: EventModifiers = .none) -> some View {
        keyboardShortcut(key, sender: keyInputSubject, modifiers: modifiers)
    }
}

public func keyboardShortcut<Sender, Label>(
    _ key: KeyEquivalent,
    sender: Sender,
    modifiers: EventModifiers = .none,
    @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label
) -> some View where Label: View, Sender: Subject, Sender.Output == KeyEquivalent {
    Button(action: { sender.send(key) }, label: label)
        .keyboardShortcut(key, modifiers: modifiers)
}


public func keyboardShortcut<Sender>(
    _ key: KeyEquivalent,
    sender: Sender,
    modifiers: EventModifiers = .none
) -> some View where Sender: Subject, Sender.Output == KeyEquivalent {
    
    guard let nameFromKey = key.name else {
        return AnyView(EmptyView())
    }
    return AnyView(keyboardShortcut(key, sender: sender, modifiers: modifiers) {
        Text("\(nameFromKey)")
    })
}


extension KeyEquivalent {
    var lowerCaseName: String? {
        switch self {
        case .space: return "space"
        case .clear: return "clear"
        case .delete: return "delete"
        case .deleteForward: return "delete forward"
        case .downArrow: return "down arrow"
        case .end: return "end"
        case .escape: return "escape"
        case .home: return "home"
        case .leftArrow: return "left arrow"
        case .pageDown: return "page down"
        case .pageUp: return "page up"
        case .return: return "return"
        case .rightArrow: return "right arrow"
        case .space: return "space"
        case .tab: return "tab"
        case .upArrow: return "up arrow"
        default: return nil
        }
    }
    
    var name: String? {
        lowerCaseName?.capitalizingFirstLetter()
    }
}

public extension EventModifiers {
    static let none = Self()
}

extension String {
    func capitalizingFirstLetter() -> String {
      return prefix(1).uppercased() + self.lowercased().dropFirst()
    }

    mutating func capitalizeFirstLetter() {
      self = self.capitalizingFirstLetter()
    }
}

extension KeyEquivalent: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        name ?? "\(character)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Code is not complete without the following two lines:
```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I had trouble adding support for characters such as keyInput("a"). I was able to solve this by changing your code slightly. If you change default: return nil for lowerCaseName to return String(self.character).lowercased(), then you will be able to use characters.

Comment: @Sajjon Adding to Command `.tab` and `.escape` don't seem to work.

Comment: How about if a key is released?

Comment: This is excellent code, but I want to alert the readers this is code that publishes the given menu click (eg: Input->left arrow) to any interested child views through the environment.

Answer (score 28):

There is no built-in native SwiftUI API for this, so far.

Here is just a demo of a possible approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.4

```
struct KeyEventHandling: NSViewRepresentable {
    class KeyView: NSView {
        override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { true }
        override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
            print(">> key \(event.charactersIgnoringModifiers ?? "")")
        }
    }

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = KeyView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async { // wait till next event cycle
            view.window?.makeFirstResponder(view)
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
    }
}

struct TestKeyboardEventHandling: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .background(KeyEventHandling())
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Demo]

Comment: thanks - unfortunately this locks up because I need to create multiple shapes and attach to shapes.  The keyboard event handling should only be activated if the shape has been selected (longPress). What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Ignore this I just realised I need to do this on the main layout window and send commands to the selected objects because more than one object may be selected.  However there is still an issue with focus handling - how does one detect when a window loses focus ?

Comment: The code works in Xcode 11.6 and macOS 10.15.6. However, there is an error sound for each key press detected.

Comment: The solution works but it just detects the alphas and arrow keys, those mods like fn, control, option, command keys does not work and whatever key pressed there was an error sound

Comment: About the error sound: if you remove `super.keyDown(with: event)` (which tells the rest responder chain that the key stroke was not handled) then the sound should no longer be emitted.

Comment: `super.keyDown(with: event)` should still be called for any keystrokes you're not handling.

Answer (score 11):

There's another solution that is very simple but only works for particular types of keys - you'd have to experiment. Just create `Buttons` with `.keyboardShortcut` modifier, but hide them visually.

```swift
Group {
    Button(action: { goAway() }) {}
        .keyboardShortcut(.escape, modifiers: [])
    Button(action: { goLeft() }) {}
        .keyboardShortcut(.upArrow, modifiers: [])
    Button(action: { goDown() }) {}
        .keyboardShortcut(.downArrow, modifiers: [])
}.opacity(0)
```

Comment: Nice. A lot cleaner than "more respected" answers

Comment: This doesn't work. I copied this exact code on the topmost level of a `ZStack`, pressing a key doesn't even trigger the action.

Comment: Works fine in a ZStack, this is such a better solution as it doesnt override the rest of your app or put something you dont want in the main menubar.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in macOS 14.0+, we now have [onKeyPress(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onkeypress(_:action:)). Huzzah!

An example, with the custom popover I'm implementing:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct AlbumModal: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
            Text("Press `escape` to dismiss.")
        }
        .onKeyPress(.escape) {
            dismiss()
            return .handled
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to any `Vstack`, `Button` etc

````swift
// adding focusable() enables onKeyPress to work
        .focusable()
        // optionally remove blue outline from focus on TextFields etc
        .focusEffectDisabled()
        // here I am detecting the escape, space, return keys 
        .onKeyPress(keys: [.escape, .space, .return]) { press in
            // perform your logic here
            // .handled signifies that key press has been successfully handled
            return .handled
        }
    ```
````