# Detect keyboard key press events on iOS / SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield, ios14

I'd like to run some code whenever the user presses certain keys while typing in a `TextField`.

For example, if I wanted to increment a variable whenever the user pressed the spacebar while typing, what would be the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61153562/how-to-detect-keyboard-events-in-swiftui-on-macos

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect keyboard events in SwiftUI on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61153562/how-to-detect-keyboard-events-in-swiftui-on-macos)

Comment: Those solutions are for MacOS. Will that work for iOS?